# WinRT ListView grouping on multiple levels

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a project where I have a list of appointments:

Appointment:

- Name
- City
- Street

I want to display those in a ListView, and group them on 2 levels, first by city, and then by street. I also want to be able to collapse the items on both levels and style the header differently.

Is something like that possible in a ListView in WinRT?

I thought about using a ListView in a ListView. But that's not possible because I want to use single selection mode. Or is there some way I can enforce this?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would keep it simple.

In the Cineworld app I created, in cinema details xaml page, I give users options to view
* Films showing today (grouped by first char)
* Films grouped by date
* All films listed (grouped by first char).

These were all very different options and I settled on a combination of radio button and multiple grouped listview (within semantic zoom).

The solution has worked well so far.